# Zend Framework decorator DL and DD style

Tags: html, zend-framework, decorator

If you add a Subform ( called "Step1" ) you will have this code:

```
<dl class="zend_form">
    <dt id="Step1-label"></dt>
    <dd id="Step1-element">
        <fieldset id="fieldset-Step1" class="Step">
            <dl>
                .....
            </dl>
        </fieldset>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

How can I add a class in the DL tag and DD tag?
For EXAMPLE:

```
<dl class="Step1DL">
<dd id="Step1-element" class="Step1DD">
```

How can I do it with the Zend Decorator?

Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

Try below code in model form file,

```
<?php
class Admin_Model_Form_Test extends Zend_Form
{
public $elementDecorators = array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors',
            array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd')),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt','class'=>'labmyaccountR'),
        ));
public $requiredElementDecorators = array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors',
            array('Description',array('escape'=>false,'tag'=>'span', 'placement' => 'append')),
            array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd')),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt','class'=>'labmyaccountR'),
        ));     
    public function EditForm($data = array())
    {
        $this->setMethod(Zend_Form::METHOD_POST);
        $this->setEncType(Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART);
            $this->setAction(
              $this->getView()->getHelper('url')->url(array(
                'controller' => 'test',
                'action'=>'edittest'
              ))
            );  

        $this->setDecorators(array(
              'Description',
              'FormElements',
              'Form'
        ));

        $fnameNotEmpty = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
        $fnameNotEmpty->setMessage('Tax value should not be empty');
        $fnameStrlen = new Zend_Validate_StringLength(1, 20);

        $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('taxvalue', array(
          'label' => 'Sales Tax *',
          'value' => $data['value'],
          'class' => 'text-size text',
          'tabindex' => '1',
          'required' => true,
          'validators' => array(
                array($fnameNotEmpty, true),
                array($fnameStrlen, true)
          ),
          'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
                  'decorators' => $this->requiredElementDecorators,                    
        ));
        $name->addValidator('Float',true);
        $this->addElement($name);

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit', array(
              'label' => 'Update',
              'tabindex' => '20',
                          'decorators' => $this->elementDecorators,                    
            ));
                $submit->removeDecorator('Label');
        $submit->removeDecorator('label');
        $this->addElement($submit);
        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('tax_id', array(
            'value' => $data['tax_id']
        ));
        $id->removeDecorator('label');
        $this->addElement($id);
        return $this;
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer... I tried to use it like this:
$SubForm_Step = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
$SubForm_Step->addDecorators($elementDecorators);

( I'm using it in a class that extends Zend_Form ) But I get this exection: 
Warning: Exception caught by form: Method getType does not exist Stack Trace: #0 C:\xampp\php\Zend\Form\Decorator\ViewHelper.php(92): Zend_Form->__call('getType', Array) #1 ....

Comment: So I tried like that:
$SubForm_Step->addDecorator(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd', 'class'=>'classnamedd'));

But it produce another DD element

 <dd class="classnamedd"></dd>
 <dt id="Step1-label"></dt>
 <dd id="Step1-element">
 
I want to modify the one that already exist NOT to create another one....

Answer (score 0):

try this, after you create the  element:
for example:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('anelement'); 
$element->addDecorators(array(array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'yourclass' )));
```